# How to set canvas as background for layout

Tags: android, canvas

In my application i have designed a canvas. I want to set the canvas as  background Resource for my layout.Can any one help me how to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yon need a Bitmap for this purpose. And the you can set the Bitmap as background for your layout.

```
public Canvas (Bitmap bitmap)
```

From the doc:

> Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into